# MPI. How to perform big CAS?

Tags: mpi

Are there some ways to perform mpi_compare_and_swap with size more than 64 bits?
Let's say that I have data structure with two fields {int, MPI_Aint} and I want to CAS it using mpi_compare_and_swap.

I tried to create derived data type and pass it as MPI_Datatype parameter, but it gives a stack error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `compare_and_swap` on datatypes that you declare yourself. The standard says:

> The parameter datatype must belong to one of the following categories
> of predefined datatypes: C integer, Fortran integer, Logical,
> Multi-language types, or Byte

where the "multi-language types" are `MPI_AINT, MPI_OFFSET, and MPI_COUNT`. Those are usually 64 bits.

Comment: Maybe you know the way that it can be avoided? I mean I use such struct to represent a node in distributed linked list {rank, offset}. And i want to implement something like harris lock-free linked list, but i should use CAS in this case.

Comment: I don't see that you need the rank: you already specify that information when you state on which process you want to do the CAS. So using only the `offset` should work.